# TeXstudio Error：Could not start build view XelaTex？

Tags: xetex, texlive, texstudio

[image]

I can use PDFlaTex, but when I use XelaTex ,error happened
[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to `options` → `Configure Texstudio` and the change the Default compiler [as in this figure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QvqRT.png) and try again

Comment: I seem understand something, I want to make sure if I change PDFlaTex   to XelaTex, so whether I need to change Build & View this Option too?

Comment: I have try it ,this time it can run normal, but when I choose XelaTex, Build & View this Option,I should choose which one , which one is better?